# Having trouble combing tibbles together when it is stored in a list, using R programming language

Tags: r, web-scraping, tibble

I am having trouble trying to combine three tibbles that are stored in a list "Tablef". Is there a way to combine them all together? I am webscrapping and some of the tables have different data type for some reason and I believe that is causing an issue when trying to row_bind "Tablef". This is in R. Here is the code I am using.

```
funko_link = "https://funko.fandom.com//wiki/Pop!_MLB"
  table_page = read_html(funko_link)
  set_name = read_html(funko_link)
  name = set_name %>% html_nodes("#firstHeading") %>% html_text() %>% gsub("[\n\t]", "", .)
  tablef = table_page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    #gets rid of the image column since it can't show images 
    lapply(., "[", -c(3))
```

This is the output for tablef to show the tibbles and how they output.

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 75 × 5
   `#`   Name              `Release Year` `Exclusivity/ Features` `Series (Team)`     
   <chr> <chr>                      <int> <lgl>                   <chr>               
 1 01    King Felix                  2017 NA                      Seattle Mariners    
 2 02    Robinson Cano               2017 NA                      Seattle Mariners    
 3 03    Kris Bryant                 2017 NA                      Chicago Cubs        
 4 04    Aaron Judge                 2017 NA                      New York Yankees    
 5 05    Bryce Harper                2017 NA                      Washington Nationals
 6 06    Anthony Rizzo               2017 NA                      Chicago Cubs        
 7 07    Clayton Kershaw             2017 NA                      Los Angeles Dodgers 
 8 08    Mike Trout                  2017 NA                      Los Angeles Angels  
 9 09    Buster Posey                2017 NA                      San Francisco Giants
10 10    Giancarlo Stanton           2017 NA                      New York Yankees    
# … with 65 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 20 × 5
     `#` Name                             `Release Year` `Exclusivity/ Features`        `Series (Team)`      
   <int> <chr>                            <chr>          <chr>                          <chr>                
 1     1 Mariner Moose                    2014           "White Uniform\nTeal Uniform"  Seattle Mariners     
 2     2 Mr. Met                          2014           "Pinstripes\nBlue Uniform"     New York Mets        
 3     3 Mr. Redlegs                      2014           "White Uniform\nRed Uniform"   Cincinnati Reds      
 4     4 Orbit                            2014           "Blue Uniform\nOrange Uniform" Houston Astros       
 5     5 Phillie Phanatic                 2014           "Pinstripes\nBlue Uniform"     Philadelphia Phillies
 6     6 Swinging Friar                   2014           ""                             San Diego Padres     
 7     7 Wally the Green Monster          2014           "White\nRed"                   Boston Red Sox       
 8     8 Bernie Brewer                    2015?          ""                             Milwaukee Brewers    
 9     9 Billy the Marlin                 20??           ""                             Miami Marlins        
10    10 Orioles Mascot (The Oriole Bird) 20??           ""                             Baltimore Orioles
```

Any help will be great thanks!

Comment: What command was giving you the error and what was the error exactly? What do you want the desired output to be when each table has different columns?

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_tibbles)` generally works... but I think your problem is that they have columns with the same names but different classes. In `[[1]]` the `Exclusivity/ Features` column is logical, but in `[[2]]` it is character. A lot of table-creating functions will let you set the column classes. Maybe you can specify that `Exclusivity/ Features` should be logical (and similarly for any other mismatched columns).

Answer (score 1):

The following approach can be considered :

```
library(rvest)

funko_link <- "https://funko.fandom.com//wiki/Pop!_MLB"
table_page <- read_html(funko_link)
set_name <- read_html(funko_link)
name <- set_name %>% html_nodes("#firstHeading") %>% html_text() %>% gsub("[\n\t]", "", .)
tablef <- table_page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  lapply(., "[", -c(3)) 

col_Names <- c("Qty", "Names", "Release Year", "Variants", "Exclusivity", "Series (Team)")
tablef <- lapply(X = tablef, FUN = function(x) {colnames(x) <- col_Names; return(x)})

do.call(rbind, tablef)

# A tibble: 109 x 6
   Qty   Names             `Release Year` Variants                                   Exclusivity                  `Series (Team)`     
   <chr> <chr>                      <int> <chr>                                      <chr>                        <chr>               
 1 1     King Felix                  2017 "White Uniform\nAlternative Uniform\nGold" "Safeco Field Exclusive"     Seattle Mariners    
 2 2     Robinson Cano               2017 "White Uniform\nTeal Uniform"              "Teal - FunkoShop Exclusive" Seattle Mariners    
 3 3     Kris Bryant                 2017 ""                                         ""                           Chicago Cubs        
 4 4     Aaron Judge                 2017 "Pinstripe Uniform\nGray Uniform"          ""                           New York Yankees    
 5 5     Bryce Harper                2017 ""                                         ""                           Washington Nationals
 6 6     Anthony Rizzo               2017 "Pinstripe Uniform\nGray Uniform"          ""                           Chicago Cubs        
 7 7     Clayton Kershaw             2017 "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"              ""                           Los Angeles Dodgers 
 8 8     Mike Trout                  2017 "White Uniform\nRed Uniform"               ""                           Los Angeles Angels  
 9 9     Buster Posey                2017 "Cream Uniform\nGray Uniform"              ""                           San Francisco Giants
10 10    Giancarlo Stanton           2017 ""                                         ""                           New York Yankees    
# i 99 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(rvest)

funko_link <- "https://funko.fandom.com//wiki/Pop!_MLB"
table_page <- read_html(funko_link)
set_name <- read_html(funko_link)
name <- set_name %>% html_nodes("#firstHeading") %>% html_text() %>% gsub("[\n\t]", "", .)
tablef <- table_page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  lapply(., "[", -c(3)) 

tablef <- lapply(X = tablef, FUN = function(x) as.matrix(x))

merged_Table <- do.call(rbind, tablef)
merged_Table

#    Name                               Release Year Variants                                          
  [1,] " 1" "King Felix"                       "2017"       "White Uniform\nAlternative Uniform\nGold"        
  [2,] " 2" "Robinson Cano"                    "2017"       "White Uniform\nTeal Uniform"                     
  [3,] " 3" "Kris Bryant"                      "2017"       ""                                                
  [4,] " 4" "Aaron Judge"                      "2017"       "Pinstripe Uniform\nGray Uniform"                 
  [5,] " 5" "Bryce Harper"                     "2017"       ""                                                
  [6,] " 6" "Anthony Rizzo"                    "2017"       "Pinstripe Uniform\nGray Uniform"                 
  [7,] " 7" "Clayton Kershaw"                  "2017"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
  [8,] " 8" "Mike Trout"                       "2017"       "White Uniform\nRed Uniform"                      
  [9,] " 9" "Buster Posey"                     "2017"       "Cream Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
 [10,] "10" "Giancarlo Stanton"                "2017"       ""                                                
 [11,] "11" "Noah Syndergaard"                 "2019"       "Pinstripe Uniform\nGray Uniform"                 
 [12,] "11" "Edgar Martinez"                   "2018"       "White Uniform\nRookie Uniform\nBronze"           
 [13,] "12" "Jose Altuve"                      "2018"       "White Uniform\nOrange Uniform"                   
 [14,] "13" "Chris Sale"                       "2018"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
 [15,] "14" "Yadier Molina"                    "2018"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
 [16,] "15" "Wil Myers"                        "2018"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
 [17,] "16" "Max Scherzer"                     "2018"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform"                     
 [18,] "17" "Mookie Betts"                     "2018"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform\nNavy Blue Uniform"  
 [19,] "18" "Francisco Lindor"                 "2018"       "Navy Blue Uniform\nGray Uniform"                 
 [20,] "19" "Nelson Cruz"                      "2018"       ""                                                
 [21,] "20" "Joey Votto"                       "2018"       "Red Uniform\nGold"                               
 [22,] "21" "Nelson Cruz"                      "2018"       "White Uniform\nTeal Uniform\nSilver"             
 [23,] "22" "Justin Verlander"                 "2018"       ""                                                
 [24,] "23" "J.D. Martinez"                    "2018"       ""                                                
 [25,] "24" "Ken Griffey Jr."                  "2018"       "White Uniform\nRookie Uniform\nBronze"           
 [26,] "25" "Juan Soto"                        "2019"       ""                                                
 [27,] "26" "Ronald Acuna Jr"                  "2019"       ""                                                
 [28,] "27" "Khris Davis"                      "2019"       ""                                                
 [29,] "28" "Blake Snell"                      "2019"       ""                                                
 [30,] "29" "Aaron Nola"                       "2019"       ""                                                
 [31,] "30" "Eugenio Suarez"                   "2019"       "White Uniform\nGold"                             
 [32,] "31" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [33,] "32" "Freddie Freeman"                  "2019"       ""                                                
 [34,] "33" "Yadier Molina"                    "2019"       "Powder Blue Uniform\nGold\nPlatinum"             
 [35,] "34" "Bryce Harper"                     "2020"       ""                                                
 [36,] "35" "Paul Goldschmidt"                 "2020"       ""                                                
 [37,] "36" "Jacob deGrom"                     "2020"       ""                                                
 [38,] "37" "Pete Alonso"                      "2020"       ""                                                
 [39,] "38" "Cody Bellinger"                   "2020"       ""                                                
 [40,] "39" "Nolan Arenado"                    "2020"       ""                                                
 [41,] "40" "Vladimir Guerrero Jr."            "2020"       ""                                                
 [42,] "41" "Christian Yelich"                 "2020"       ""                                                
 [43,] "42" "Austin Meadows"                   "2020"       ""                                                
 [44,] "43" "Corey Kluber"                     "2020"       ""                                                
 [45,] "44" "Freddie Freeman"                  "2020"       ""                                                
 [46,] "45" "Josh Bell"                        "2020"       ""                                                
 [47,] "46" "Xander Bogaerts"                  "2020"       ""                                                
 [48,] "47" "Charlie Blackmon"                 "2020"       ""                                                
 [49,] "48" "Gleyber Torres"                   "2020"       ""                                                
 [50,] "49" "Gary Sanchez"                     "2020"       ""                                                
 [51,] "50" "Alex Bregman"                     "2020"       ""                                                
 [52,] "51" "Ichiro"                           "2019"       "White Uniform\nNavy Blue Uniform\nSilver"        
 [53,] "52" "Eric Davis"                       "2021"       "White Uniform\nSilver"                           
 [54,] "53" "Ozzie Smith"                      "2022"       "Gray Uniform\nGold"                              
 [55,] "54" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [56,] "55" "Pedro Martinez"                   "2022"       "White Uniform\nGray Uniform\nGold"               
 [57,] "56" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [58,] "57" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [59,] "58" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [60,] "59" ""                                 NA           ""                                                
 [61,] "60" "Anthony Rendon"                   "2021"       ""                                                
 [62,] "61" "Ozzie Albies"                     "2021"       ""                                                
 [63,] "62" "Christian Yelich"                 "2021"       ""                                                
 [64,] "63" "Cody Bellinger"                   "2021"       ""                                                
 [65,] "64" "Javier Báez"                      "2021"       ""                                                
 [66,] "65" "Corey Seager"                     "2021"       ""                                                
 [67,] "66" "Stephen Strasburg"                "2021"       ""                                                
 [68,] "67" "Fernando Tatís Jr."               "2021"       ""                                                
 [69,] "68" "Pete Alonso"                      "2021"       ""                                                
 [70,] "69" "Whit Merrifield"                  "2021"       ""                                                
 [71,] "70" "José Berríos"                     "2021"       ""                                                
 [72,] "71" "Vladimir Guerrero Jr."            "2021"       ""                                                
 [73,] "72" "Gerrit Cole"                      "2021"       ""                                                
 [74,] "73" "Ketel Marte"                      "2021"       ""                                                
 [75,] "74" "Mookie Betts"                     "2021"       ""                                                
 [76,] "75" "Bo Bichette"                      "2022"       ""                                                
 [77,] "76" "Jose Altuve"                      "2022"       ""                                                
 [78,] "77" "Mookie Betts"                     "2022"       ""                                                
 [79,] "78" "Francisco Lindor"                 "2022"       ""                                                
 [80,] "79" "Max Scherzer"                     "2022"       ""                                                
 [81,] "80" "Manny Machado"                    "2022"       ""                                                
 [82,] "81" "Shohei Ohtani"                    "2022"       ""                                                
 [83,] " 1" "Mariner Moose"                    "2014"       "White Uniform\nTeal Uniform"                     
 [84,] " 2" "Mr. Met"                          "2014"       "Pinstripe Uniform\nBlue Uniform"                 
 [85,] " 3" "Mr. Redlegs"                      "2014"       "White Uniform\nRed Uniform"                      
 [86,] " 4" "Orbit"                            "2014"       "Blue Uniform\nOrange Uniform"                    
 [87,] " 5" "Phillie Phanatic"                 "2014"       "Pinstripe Uniform\nPowder Blue Uniform"          
 [88,] " 6" "Swinging Friar"                   "2014"       "Swinging Bat"                                    
 [89,] " 7" "Wally the Green Monster"          "2014"       "White Uniform\nRed Uniform"                      
 [90,] " 8" "Bernie Brewer"                    "2019"       ""                                                
 [91,] " 9" "Billy the Marlin"                 "2019"       ""                                                
 [92,] "10" "Orioles Mascot (The Oriole Bird)" "2019"       ""                                                
 [93,] "11" "Paws"                             "2019"       ""                                                
 [94,] "12" "Athletics Mascot (Stomper)"       "2019"       ""                                                
 [95,] "13" "Sluggerrr"                        "2019"       ""                                                
 [96,] "14" "TC Bear"                          "2019"       ""                                                
 [97,] "15" "Theodore Roosevelt"               "2019"       ""                                                
 [98,] "16" "Swinging Friar"                   "2019"       ""                                                
 [99,] "17" "Pirate Parrot"                    "2019"       "Bat on Shoulder"                                 
[100,] "18" "White Sox Mascot (Southpaw)"      "2019"       ""                                                
[101,] "19" "Blue Jays Mascot (Ace)"           "2019"       ""                                                
[102,] "20" "Rangers Captain"                  "2019"       ""                                                
[103,] "2"  "Shohei Ohtani"                    "2019"       "White Uniforms\nRed Uniforms"                    
[104,] " 2" "Babe Ruth"                        "2019"       "Gray Uniform"                                    
[105,] " 3" "Babe Ruth (Home Run)"             "2019"       "Pinstripe Uniform"                               
[106,] " 4" "Babe Ruth (Called Shot)"          "2019"       "Black and White"                                 
[107,] "11" "Derek Jeter"                      "2022"       "Clean Pinstripe Uniform\nDirty Pinstripe Uniform"
[108,] "42" "Jackie Robinson"                  "2022"       "White Uniform\nBronze\nSliding"                  
[109,] "SE" "Kevin  Kiermaier"                 "2018"       "Star Wars Han Solo"                              
       Exclusivity                               Series (Team)          
  [1,] "Safeco Field Exclusive"                  "Seattle Mariners"     
  [2,] "Teal - FunkoShop Exclusive"              "Seattle Mariners"     
  [3,] ""                                        "Chicago Cubs"         
  [4,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
  [5,] ""                                        "Washington Nationals" 
  [6,] ""                                        "Chicago Cubs"         
  [7,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
  [8,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Angels"   
  [9,] ""                                        "San Francisco Giants" 
 [10,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
 [11,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [12,] "T-Mobile Park Exclusive"                 "Seattle Mariners"     
 [13,] ""                                        "Houston Astros"       
 [14,] ""                                        "Boston Red Sox"       
 [15,] ""                                        "St. Louis Cardinals"  
 [16,] ""                                        "San Diego Padres"     
 [17,] ""                                        "Washington Nationals" 
 [18,] "Navy Blue Uniform -\nFanatics Exclusive" "Boston Red Sox"       
 [19,] ""                                        "Cleveland Indians"    
 [20,] ""                                        "Seattle Mariners"     
 [21,] "Great American\nBallpark Exclusive"      "Cincinnati Reds"      
 [22,] "Safeco Field Exclusive"                  "Seattle Mariners"     
 [23,] ""                                        "Houston Astros"       
 [24,] ""                                        "Boston Red Sox"       
 [25,] "Safeco Field Exclusive"                  "Seattle Mariners"     
 [26,] ""                                        "Washington Nationals" 
 [27,] ""                                        "Atlanta Braves"       
 [28,] ""                                        "Oakland Athletics"    
 [29,] ""                                        "Tampa Bay Rays"       
 [30,] ""                                        "Philadelphia Phillies"
 [31,] "Great American\nBallpark Exclusive"      "Cincinnati Reds"      
 [32,] ""                                        ""                     
 [33,] "Truist Park Exclusive"                   "Atlanta Braves"       
 [34,] "Busch Stadium Exclusive"                 "St. Louis Cardinals"  
 [35,] ""                                        "Philadelphia Phillies"
 [36,] ""                                        "St. Louis Cardinals"  
 [37,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [38,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [39,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
 [40,] ""                                        "Colorado Rockies"     
 [41,] ""                                        "Toronto Blue Jays"    
 [42,] ""                                        "Milwaukee Brewers"    
 [43,] ""                                        "Tampa Bay Rays"       
 [44,] ""                                        "Texas Rangers"        
 [45,] ""                                        "Atlanta Braves"       
 [46,] ""                                        "Pittsburgh Pirates"   
 [47,] ""                                        "Boston Red Sox"       
 [48,] ""                                        "Colorado Rockies"     
 [49,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
 [50,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
 [51,] ""                                        "Houston Astros"       
 [52,] "T-Mobile Park Exclusive"                 "Seattle Mariners"     
 [53,] "Great American\nBallpark Exclusive"      "Cincinnati Reds"      
 [54,] "Busch Stadium Exclusive"                 "St. Louis Cardinals"  
 [55,] ""                                        ""                     
 [56,] "Fenway Park Exclusive"                   "Boston Red Sox"       
 [57,] ""                                        ""                     
 [58,] ""                                        ""                     
 [59,] ""                                        ""                     
 [60,] ""                                        ""                     
 [61,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Angels"   
 [62,] ""                                        "Atlanta Braves"       
 [63,] ""                                        "Milwaukee Brewers"    
 [64,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
 [65,] ""                                        "Chicago Cubs"         
 [66,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
 [67,] ""                                        "Washington Nationals" 
 [68,] ""                                        "San Diego Padres"     
 [69,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [70,] ""                                        "Kansas City Royals"   
 [71,] ""                                        "Minnesota Twins"      
 [72,] ""                                        "Toronto Blue Jays"    
 [73,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
 [74,] ""                                        "Arizona Diamondbacks" 
 [75,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
 [76,] "Canada Exclusive"                        "Toronto Blue Jays"    
 [77,] ""                                        "Houston Astros"       
 [78,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
 [79,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [80,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [81,] ""                                        "San Diego Padres"     
 [82,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Angels"   
 [83,] "T-Mobile Park Exclusive"                 "Seattle Mariners"     
 [84,] ""                                        "New York Mets"        
 [85,] ""                                        "Cincinnati Reds"      
 [86,] ""                                        "Houston Astros"       
 [87,] ""                                        "Philadelphia Phillies"
 [88,] ""                                        "San Diego Padres"     
 [89,] ""                                        "Boston Red Sox"       
 [90,] ""                                        "Milwaukee Brewers"    
 [91,] ""                                        "Miami Marlins"        
 [92,] ""                                        "Baltimore Orioles"    
 [93,] ""                                        "Detroit Tigers"       
 [94,] ""                                        "Oakland Athletics"    
 [95,] ""                                        "Kansas City Royals"   
 [96,] ""                                        "Minnesota Twins"      
 [97,] ""                                        "Washington Nationals" 
 [98,] ""                                        "San Diego Padres"     
 [99,] ""                                        "Pittsburgh Pirates"   
[100,] ""                                        "Chicago White Sox"    
[101,] ""                                        "Toronto Blue Jays"    
[102,] ""                                        "Texas Rangers"        
[103,] "Red Uniforms -\nFanatics Exclusive"      "Los Angeles Angels"   
[104,] ""                                        "New York Yankees"     
[105,] "New York Comicon Exclusive"              "New York Yankees"     
[106,] "Walmart Exclusive"                       "New York Yankees"     
[107,] "FunkoShop Exclusive"                     "New York Yankees"     
[108,] ""                                        "Los Angeles Dodgers"  
[109,] "Tropicana Field Exclusive"               "Tampa Bay Rays"
```

Comment: Why would you transform a dataframe to a matrix? That would lead to everything being coerced to character??. why not directly rbind the dataframes??

Comment: When you convert to character, you eliminate some problems. You can try merged_Table <- do.call(bind_rows, tablef) and merged_Table <- do.call(rbind, tablef) but these commands generate bugs. Also, from my point of view, I do not see the problem of having the information as a matrix of characters.

Comment: Why use `do.call` with `bind_rows`??? Also if `bind_rows(tablef)` or even `do.call(rbind, tablef)` do not work, then `do.call(rbind, lapply(tablef, as.matrix))` will definitely be incorrect/inconsistent. the reason the first two are not working is because of different names in each table. That does not mean you should just change the data to matrix and rbind them. That is a VERY wrong approach. Also you should always strive to aintain the data class as previously intended. changing numbers to character is not ideal

Comment: I disagree because all the tables have the same number of columns :  lapply(tablef, FUN = function(x) dim(x))
[[1]]
[1] 82  6

[[2]]
[1] 20  6

[[3]]
[1] 1 6

[[4]]
[1] 5 6

[[5]]
[1] 1 6 From my point of view, the approach that I proposed will not generate inconsistencies because all the tables have the same number of columns.

Comment: The columns names are : [[1]]
[1] "#"             "Name"          "Release Year"  "Variants"      "Exclusivity"   "Series (Team)"

[[2]]
[1] "#"             "Name"          "Release Year"  "Variants"      "Exclusivity"   "Series (Team)"

[[3]]
[1] "Qty"           "Names"         "Release Year"  "Variants"      "Exclusivity"   "Series (Team)"

[[4]]
[1] "#"             "Name"          "Release Year"  "Variants"      "Exclusivity"   "Series (Team)"

[[5]]
[1] "#"   "Name"  "Release Year"  "Variants"  "Exclusivity"   "Series (Team)" On one of the data.frames, we have Qty instead of #

Comment: just because the have same dimension does not mean they have similar names. The issue can either be names or class. eg try `l <- list(data.frame(x=1), data.frame(y=TRUE))` both dataframes have 1 value, but you cannot use `do.call(rbind, l)` and then try `m <- list(data.frame(x=1), data.frame(x='2'))` they try `bind_rows(m)` Then you will understand what I mean

Comment: Yes, I know, I mentioned it in my previous comment ;) Maybe I am wrong, but my understanding is that the person wants to extract all the tables of the website and put all the information into one table and the approach I proposed achieves this.

Comment: The current approach is correct. The previous approach of transforming to matrix was incorrect

Comment: The only column that is not a character with the "non-matrix approach" is the column "Release Year". In this particular case, from my point of view, there is not a big  loss of information to convert the data.frame / tibble to a matrix because all the columns, except one, are character columns. I am not sure the matrix approach is a wrong approach. Anyway, I hope this is helpful. Thank you for this exchange!